# How to accept only last API call while typing?

Tags: javascript

I have a use case when I do not want to use debounce wrapper around the fetch data function while typing. The fetch data function returns items to display. I want to ensure that the items to display are reassigned only for the last API call. What is the proper way to do so?

Not sure, if this piece of code can help:

```
const handleInput = async (input) => {
  items = await fetchData(input)
}
```

Comment: Well using debounce is the proper way to do this.

Comment: I would think the "proper" approach would be to debounce the input so the operation isn't performed with every keystroke but only when the typing pauses.  Can you indicate why you don't want to do this?

Comment: You could cancel the fetch using an abort signal (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/signal)

Comment: You don't want to debounce, but you do want to process only the values returned by the most recent event? What do you see as the difference between debouncing and only-pay-attention-to-the-last?

Comment: @DaveNewton I did not explain well myself. I meant I do want to change the variable as you type, but I want to ensure that earlier results of API calls do not overwrite the later ones. Anyways, thanks!